# about the grid view EditButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm new to asp.net and writing some program for doing some update delete action. i've created a gridview and connecting db program, now i want to enable the edit button and but alter it pass the id from the editGrid.aspx to the editDetials.aspx which let user can edit the content in a details view.

here is the script in editGrid.aspx

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

how to make it pass the id value using the gridview edit button?

Comment: what kind of code you are using to bind gridview. Only then some one will able to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DataKeyNames property of gridview
[Here is an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx)